# Ajax Form inserts data twice in database php mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, forms

**The Scenario**

I have a html form (index.php) which submits data using ajax to an external file (register.php) which does the parsing job and inserts data into mysql table.

**The Problem**

When the form is submitted, it inserts the data **twice** in the database. I searched everywhere but could not find any solution.

**Here is my code:**

**index.php (form):**

```
<form name="register" id="register" class="col-md-12 form-horizontal" role="form" onsubmit="submitForm(); return false;">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="regname" class="control-label"  >Name:*</label>
    <input name="regname" type="text" class="form-control" id="regname" placeholder="Please provide your Name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="regmobile" class="control-label">Mobile No.:*</label>
    <input name="regmobile" type="text" class="form-control" id="regmobile" placeholder="Your Mobile Number">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="regvillage" class="control-label">Village/City:*</label>
    <input name="regvillage" type="text" class="form-control" id="regvillage" placeholder="Your Village Name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="regdistrict" class="control-label">District:*</label>
    <select name="regdistrict" id="regdistrict" class="form-control" data-allow-clear="true" data-placeholder="Select District" style="width:100%">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="Ahmedabad">Ahmedabad</option>
    <option value="Amreli">Amreli</option>
    <option value="Anand">Anand</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <hr>
    <span id="status"></span></br>
    <button type="submit" name="submitbtn" id="submitbtn" class="pull-right btn btn-primary">Register</button>
</div>
</form>
```

**index.php (Ajax)**

```
<script>
function _(id){ return document.getElementById(id); }
function submitForm(){
_("submitbtn").disabled = true;
_("status").innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append( "regname", _("regname").value );
formdata.append( "regmobile", _("regmobile").value );
formdata.append( "regvillage", _("regvillage").value );
formdata.append( "regdistrict", _("regdistrict").value );
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open( "POST", "register.php" );
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
        if(ajax.responseText == "success"){
            _("register").innerHTML = '<h4>Thanks '+_("regname").value+', your registration is complete.</h4>';
        } else {
            _("status").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            _("submitbtn").disabled = false;
        }
    }
}
ajax.send( formdata );
}
</script>
```

**register.php**

```
<?php  require_once('caligrodb.php'); ?> //database connection config file
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['regname']) && isset($_POST['regmobile']) && isset($_POST['regvillage']) && isset($_POST['regdistrict'])){
    $regname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['regname']);
    $regmobile = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['regmobile']);
    $regvillage = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['regvillage']);
    $regdistrict = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['regdistrict']);

    mysql_select_db($database_caligrodb, $caligrodb);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO contacts(contactname, contactno, contactvillage, contactdistrict, subscribed) VALUES ('$regname', '$regmobile', '$regvillage', '$regdistrict', '1')");

    echo "success";
} else {
    echo"Kindly fill the form & submit the data!";
};
?>
```

Can anyone help me in find whats wrong with this code?

Comment: Try adding an `event.preventDefault()` https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: Oh and you are planning on using a prepared statement and switching over to mysqli or pdo, right? I hope so.

Comment: how you called the submitForm function i can't see it.

Comment: @HassanAli - Its there in the form `onsubmit="submitForm(); return false;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake:

The `onsubmit="submitForm(); return false;` is applied to the **form tag**. I removed it from there and instead I added `onclick="submitForm(); returnfalse;` to the **submit button**.

Now its working as expacted.